# Stock Android app manager requires app to be Force Stopped even though it is not running

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, force-close, force-stop

When I go into the stock Android KitKat stock app manager, many apps indicate that they require being Force Stopped before they can be moved to external storage, whereas other apps do not.

This would make sense if the apps requiring Force Stop were running, or were running a service.  But they are not.

An example is the game [Little Crane](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steenriver.littlecrane).  The game is not running, nor has it been run since the phone rebooted.  Using OS Monitor, I see no processes related to that app.  Yet, the stock Android app manager indicates that the app must be Force Stopped before it can be moved to external storage.  This implies that Android thinks that a thread related to the game is running.

Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Comment: Interesting and perhaps somebody may also shed some light on why Force Stop button is not greyed out if there is no active process for the app?

Comment: @Firelord Yes, exactly.  Can you confirm this phenomenon?